# Json transformation using Jolt to convert hours into seconds

Tags: json, jolt

I have input json where fields as `"runtime": "01:45:23"` should be converted into `seconds`(`Integer`) using Jolt. There are other fields changes as well needed and those are compeleted but I am stuck with the conversion of runtime

Input JSON :

```json
{
  "title_info": {
    "titleId": "3518864",
    "contentType": "Episode",
    "titleBrief": "Beirut S1: 04",
    "runtime": "01:45:23",
    "caption": "Yes"
  }
}
```

Output :

```json
{
  "titleId": "3518864",
  "contentType": "Episode",
  "caption": true,
  "runtime": 6323
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no function for multiplication in Jolt, but you can use ***divide*** within a **modify** spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "title_info": {
        "t": "=split(':',@(1,runtime))",
        //"min_": "@(1,time_portions)",
        "time_portions": "=toInteger(@(1,t))",
        "rate0": "=divide(1,3600)",
        "rate1": "=divide(1,60)",
        "tp0_": "@(1,time_portions[0])",
        "tp0": "=divide(@(1,tp0_),@(1,rate0))",
        "tp1_": "@(1,time_portions[1])",
        "tp1": "=divide(@(1,tp1_),@(1,rate1))",
        "tp2": "@(1,time_portions[2])",
        "runtime": "=intSum(@(1,tp0),@(1,tp1),@(1,tp2))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "titleId|c*|runtime": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```